# Python Optimal Transport Gromov distance is non zero for identical inputs

Tags: python

I was using Fused-Gromov-Wasserstein distance (all computed with Python Optimal Transport library `pot` ) to measure a distance between graphs, and when I wanted to compute the FGW distance between a distribution and itself, it was non zero.
I then searched for a moment and I found out that when I used the Gromov distance on that distribution and itself, it was also non zero.

In my example, I used the distance matrix between all nodes on a binary tree with depth 3, and a uniform histogram to compute the distance.
Here is my code :

```
import ot
from ot.gromov import gromov_wasserstein2, gromov_wasserstein
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def triangle_inequality(C):
    #C[i, j] should be a metric from i to j
    n = C.shape[0]
    if C.shape[1] != n:
         print("Shape do not match a metric")
         return False
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            for k in range(n):
                    if C[i, j] > C[i, k] + C[k, j]:
                        print(f"No triangle inequality : {i} -> {k} -> {j} < {i} -> {j}")
                        return False
    return True

def gromov_value(C1, C2, T):
    n = C1.shape[0]
    m = C2.shape[0]

    v = 0

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            for k in range(n):
                for l in range(m):
                    v += ((C1[i, k] - C2[j, l])**2)*T[i, j]*T[k, l]
    return v

C = np.array([
    [0., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
    [1., 0., 2., 1., 1., 3., 3., 2., 2., 2., 2., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
    [1., 2., 0., 3., 3., 1., 1., 4., 4., 4., 4., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
    [2., 1., 3., 0., 2., 4., 4., 1., 1., 3., 3., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
    [2., 1., 3., 2., 0., 4., 4., 3., 3., 1., 1., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
    [2., 3., 1., 4., 4., 0., 2., 5., 5., 5., 5., 1., 1., 3., 3.],
    [2., 3., 1., 4., 4., 2., 0., 5., 5., 5., 5., 3., 3., 1., 1.],
    [3., 2., 4., 1., 3., 5., 5., 0., 2., 4., 4., 6., 6., 6., 6.],
    [3., 2., 4., 1., 3., 5., 5., 2., 0., 4., 4., 6., 6., 6., 6.],
    [3., 2., 4., 3., 1., 5., 5., 4., 4., 0., 2., 6., 6., 6., 6.],
    [3., 2., 4., 3., 1., 5., 5., 4., 4., 2., 0., 6., 6., 6., 6.],
    [3., 4., 2., 5., 5., 1., 3., 6., 6., 6., 6., 0., 2., 4., 4.],
    [3., 4., 2., 5., 5., 1., 3., 6., 6., 6., 6., 2., 0., 4., 4.],
    [3., 4., 2., 5., 5., 3., 1., 6., 6., 6., 6., 4., 4., 0., 2.],
    [3., 4., 2., 5., 5., 3., 1., 6., 6., 6., 6., 4., 4., 2., 0.]
],dtype=np.float64)
#Shortest path lengths of a tree with arity 2 and depth 3

print(f"Symetric : {np.all(C == np.transpose(C))}")
print(f"Triangle : {triangle_inequality(C)}")

n = C.shape[0]

h = ot.unif(n)

GW = gromov_wasserstein(C, C, h, h)
Id = np.identity(n) / n

gw = gromov_value(C, C, GW)
gwid = gromov_value(C, C, Id)

print(GW*n)
print(f"POT GW2 value : {gromov_wasserstein2(C, C, h, h)}")
print(f"Hand computed GW2 value from GW : {gw}")
print(f"Hand computed GW2 value with Id : {gwid}")


plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(GW, cmap='Blues', interpolation='nearest')
plt.title('Gromov from C to C')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(Id, cmap='Blues', interpolation='nearest')
plt.title("Identity")
plt.show()
```

Output :

```
Symetric : True
Triangle : True
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
POT GW2 value : 3.484444444444449
Hand computed GW2 value from GW : 3.484444444444445
Hand computed GW2 value with Id : 0.0
```

[Representation of matrixes with matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXDAg.png)

The expectation is that the gromov distance should be 0, and `gromov_wasserstein` should find the coupling that minimizes the sum computed in my function `gromov_value`. However, `gromov_wasserstein` does not return what is expected.

It seems too simple to be a bug in the library, so maybe there is something I don't get in how to use POT's functions.

**Edit**

I discovered the function `ot.gromov.GW_distance_estimation` which does what my function `gromov_values` does, but probably way better, and the results are exactly the same.

What is more, after printing the logs of `gromov_wasserstein`, I saw that the algorithm converges quickly. It might be a local minimum, since when I start with `G0=Id` when computing `gromov_wasserstein`, the algorithm converges immediately into the right value (Id).

But `gromov_wasserstein` do not provide any method to start from a random transport plan. Any one knows how to generate a random transport plan which satisfies two histograms (positives vectors which sums to one) `p` and `q` ?